# Eclipse cannot find existing project in build path

Tags: java, eclipse, build, path

Here is probably one of the idiosyncrasies of Eclipse and its handling of build paths, which cannot be fixed despite all sorts of workarounds tested so far.

The issue relates to a workspace of several projects, each of which compiles into its own JAR.

Dependencies among the projects are resolved by adding the relevant ones to the build path (no `Maven` or other external tool or plugin is used), via

```
Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects
```

Among all these projects, a couple (say, `com.example.p1` and `com.example.p2`) refuse to recognize a third (and simple) one (say, `com.example.p3`), while all other projects do. So, although P3 is added to the build path, all related classes from P3 are imported properly and the source code of each such class is accessible by hitting `F3`, Eclipse keeps complaining that

```
The import com.example.p3 cannot be resolved
```

and

```
SomeClass cannot be resolved to a type
```

where `com.example.p3.SomeClass` is one of the P3 classes.

If instead of the P3 project I put its compiled JAR in the build path, the issue disappears. However, code in P3 changes frequently and it is a time waste to keep compiling and refreshing the workspace so that the change is picked up, not to mention that this should not happen in an IDE anyway (and it does not for the other projects using P3, in the very same Eclipse workspace).

I've tried:

- Removing and adding again P1, P2, P3
- Cleaning up and recompiling everything
- Checking whether any other project loads the P3 JAR
- Putting P3 at the top of the Eclipse build path "Order and Export" list
- Using the "Fix project setup" suggestion of Eclipse (available when hovering the mouse over the red-underlined-error compilation line). Actually, this option offers adding to the build path either P3 or its JAR, but if P3 is added, the issue reappears.

The `.classpath` files in P1 and P2 when using the P3 source (not the JAR) are identical to all other projects and look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="classes" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="JRE_LIB" sourcepath="JRE_SRC"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="<JAR_path/JAR_file>"/> 
    ... // Multiple other JAR files
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/p3/">
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

The `.project` files are also the same for all the projects in the workspace.

Any ideas?

Comment: any ideas ... excepted using maven/Ivy/any kind of dependency manager ? I guess you may have some strange circular dependency issue, but can't be sure of it. Beside, when you say "refuse to recognize a third", how does it shows up , Is project `com.example.p3` simply invisible ? or is it present, but with a wrong project nature ?

Comment: Does P3 export its contents from the Exports tab?  Can you post the .classpath files from all 3?

Comment: The p3/src box is ticked as with all other projects in "Order and Export". I have updated the question with the structure of the .classpath file, but there is not much more to this, all such files in the workspace are similar.